# Enabling and Disabling Collider based on direction in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

I would think this would be simple but for some reason, I can't figure this out. I have 4 child GameObjects around my player, each one with it's own collider. I need to be able to enable and disable the child GameObjects based on the direction the character is moving. So if the player is moving right the left, top and bottom colliders will be disabled leaving just the right collider active. If the Player moves up then the Left, Right, and Bottom colliders will be disabled leaving just the Top collider. And it's the same principle for the other 2 directions. But for some reason, my code works for both the left and right directions, but when my character moves up or down it disables everything except the left collider. Can I get some help? Here is my code:

```
public BasicNPCPrototype NPCPrototype;
    private bool nearNPC = false;

    public bool facingRight;
    public bool facingUp;

    public GameObject RightCollider;
    public GameObject LeftCollider;
    public GameObject TopCollider;
    public GameObject BottomCollider;

    // Use this for initialization
    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    protected override void Update()
    {
        // Call the GetInput Function
        GetInput();

        // Call the CheckIfNear function
        CheckIfNear();

        // Call the CheckDirection function
        CheckDirection();

        // Call the DisableInteractionColliders function
        DisableInteractionColliders();

        base.Update();
    }

    void GetInput()
    {
        if(playerActive)
        {
            direction = Vector2.zero;

            // Get the horizontal Axis and put in the X value of "direction"
            direction.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            // Get the Vertical Axis and put in the Y value of "direction"
            direction.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        }    
    }

    // Look at our movement direction and decide which way were facing
    void CheckDirection()
    {
        if (direction.x > 0)
        {
            facingRight = true;
            facingUp = false;
        }
        else if (direction.x < 0)
        {
            facingRight = false;
            facingUp = false;
        }

        if (direction.y > 0) // && !facingRight)
        {
            facingUp = true;
            facingRight = false;
        }
        else if (direction.y < 0) // && !facingRight)
        {
            facingUp = false;
            facingRight = false;
        }

    }

    // Look at what direction the Player is facing and disable/enable the correct colliders to account for it
    void DisableInteractionColliders()
    {
        // WIP
        if(facingRight)
        {
            RightCollider.SetActive(true);
            LeftCollider.SetActive(false);
            TopCollider.SetActive(false);
            BottomCollider.SetActive(false);
        } else if(!facingRight)
        {
            LeftCollider.SetActive(true);
            RightCollider.SetActive(false);
            TopCollider.SetActive(false);
            BottomCollider.SetActive(false);
        }

         else if(facingUp)
        {
            TopCollider.SetActive(true);
            RightCollider.SetActive(false);
            LeftCollider.SetActive(false);
            BottomCollider.SetActive(false);
        } else if(!facingUp)
        {
            BottomCollider.SetActive(true);
            RightCollider.SetActive(false);
            LeftCollider.SetActive(false);
            TopCollider.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

If it's easier to read you can read it over on PasteBin: https://pastebin.com/y1jQT17w

Ignore the CheckIfNear(); call in teh update function as that's for future plans but it currently empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if(facingRight)
    {
        RightCollider.SetActive(true);
        LeftCollider.SetActive(false);
        TopCollider.SetActive(false);
        BottomCollider.SetActive(false);
    } 
    else if(!facingRight)
    {
        LeftCollider.SetActive(true);
        RightCollider.SetActive(false);
        TopCollider.SetActive(false);
        BottomCollider.SetActive(false);
    }

    else if(facingUp)
    {
        TopCollider.SetActive(true);
        RightCollider.SetActive(false);
        LeftCollider.SetActive(false);
        BottomCollider.SetActive(false);
    } 
    else if(!facingUp)
    {
        BottomCollider.SetActive(true);
        RightCollider.SetActive(false);
        LeftCollider.SetActive(false);
        TopCollider.SetActive(false);
    }
```

facingRight is either True or False. This means that your first pair of if statement (`if(facingRight)` and `if(!facingRight)`) is always true, so your code never reaches the 3rd if statement and your variable facingUp is never used.

If I were you I would assign used an integer to store the direction and select the colliders using a switch. Like this:

```
int dir = 0;

void CheckDirection()
{
    if (direction.x > 0)
    {
        dir = 1;
    }
    else if (direction.x < 0)
    {
        dir = 2;
    }

    if (direction.y > 0)
    {
        dir = 3;
    }
    else if (direction.y < 0)
    {
        dir = 4;
    }

}
```

.

```
void DisableInteractionColliders()
{
        LeftCollider.SetActive(false);
        RightCollider.SetActive(false);
        TopCollider.SetActive(false);
        BottomCollider.SetActive(false);

        switch(dir)
        {
            case 1: RightCollider.SetActive(true);
                    break;
            case 2: LeftCollider.SetActive(true);
                    break;
            case 3: TopCollider.SetActive(true);
                    break;
            case 4: BottomCollider.SetActive(true);
                    break;

            default: break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Ok, however, this causes an issue that I also did not foresee and don't know how to fix, there is a variable at the top of the script called near NPC. When a collider touches the NPC sets the variable to true, but then the collider gets disabled when the player moves away and nearNPC is still set to true allowing the player to talk to the NPC from anywhere after getting near them, I will update my script here and on pastebin to show this. But how do I fix it?

Comment: Normally you keep all of your RayCast or Colliders active and use them to prevent mouvement in a certain direction instead. In your case you would keep all 4 colliders active and disable mouvement in a direction in your Move() or CheckDirection() function.

Comment: The Colliders are Triggers, my problem is I don't need to talk to the NPC when the player gets near but instead when the player presses a key. Here is the full script plus the updates you gave: https://pastebin.com/ZsdDQs3s

Comment: @UltraGamer Join me in [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/190594/npc-interaction?tab=general)